# How to pass payload to Bitbucket api to enable Yaac(yet another commit checker) using Python

Tags: python, ui-automation, bitbucket-api

I am trying to enable YAAC (Yet another commit checker) using Bitbucket api programatically
(Python 3.7), but somehow the payload looks not good and getting status code as **400**, with an error **expected a valid value (number, String, array), "exceptionName":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException""**

Can someone please help me out here?

```
import requests

def stash_status():

    headers = { "Authorization": f'Bearer token',
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json" }

    payload {
            "key": "com.isroot.stash.plugin.yacc:yaccHook",
            "name": "Yet Another Commit Checker",
            "type": "PRE_RECEIVE",
            "description": "Yet Another Commit Checker pre-receive hook",
            "configFormKey": "com.isroot.stash.plugin.yacc:yaacHook-config-form",
            "scopeTypes": [
                "REPOSITORY",
                "PROJECT"
                ],
            "enabled": "true",
            "configured": "true",
            "scope" {
                "type": "REPOSITORY",
                "resourceld": resourceld
            }}

    response = requests.put(
                    "https://${GITURL}/rest/api/latest/projects/${projectName}/repos/${repoName}/settings"
                    "/hooks/com.isroot.stash.plugin.yacc:yaccHook/enabled", verify=False, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(response.status_code) 
    print(response.content)

stash_status()
```

Comment: The plugin seems to be called YACC (which fits the whole name) and not YAAC: https://docs.mohami.io/yet-another-commit-checker-yacc/

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. updated my code